# famo.us: sub-classing Surface

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I've seen a few examples of sub-classing the "Surface" or "View" classes in famo.us.  Here's one simple example:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var View = require('famous/core/View');

    function SettingsView() {
        View.apply(this, arguments);    
        this.add(new Surface({ content: 'settings' }));
    }

    SettingsView.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
    SettingsView.prototype.constructor = SettingsView;

    SettingsView.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {};

    module.exports = SettingsView;
});
```

I have 3 questions about this:

1. What is the purpose of `View.apply(this, arguments);`?  Is this a "javascript thing" or a "famo.us thing"?
2. What if I wanted to pass width and height properties into the `SettingsView` .ctor so I could then pass them into the `View` .ctor?  Is that what the `apply` method does?
3. What is the meaning of `SettingsView.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {};`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use apply to... apply... an array of arguments to an object. A better description is found on **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

The shortform is that apply expects (1) a value for `this` and secondly an array of arguments. you'll notice in your example there is no array though. That's because if you use `arguments` you can pass all of the arguments of the enclosing function into the object that apply is being called for. In this case, the arguments passed into `SettingsView()` will be subsequently applied to a enclosed `View`

Outside of the `SettingsView` function you'll see that the prototype of `SettingsView` is being used to create a new `View`, and then we set the constructor of `SettingsView` to basically call `SettingsView()`

See how the loop completes. So when call the constructor of `SettingsView` e.g `var mySettings = new SettingsView();` all the arguments I pass through to the constructor will be passed to the constructor of the View. In addition, a `Surface` is created with the content option pre-filled to "settings." In the real world, that could be a button, or image or something that you might want to reuse.

You'll find if you look at the source of `View` there is a DEFAULT_OPTIONS object with various properties that are used if we don't explicitly state them when creating a new instance of a `View`. In your example, we're basically just clearing the contents of that object. Refer to what you need to pass to a typical famo.us View in the docs so that the View you create has all the necessary properties/options.

As for passing size properties into a View, it doesn't work like that. Think of a famo.us View as a Grouping of other famo.us renderables(Surfaces) You could however pass a variable to your SettingsView Constructor which is then used to set the width and height value of the Surface it contains. That's how you'd go about it.

I definitely recommend getting a book on this, I'm finding *[Speaking Javascript](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029564.do)* quite useful at the moment as it disposes with the usual "what is a computer program?" riff raff. Prototypes and the likes are really crucial to building JS apps, and the process occurs frequently when you're using famo.us

This might need a little bit of editing to make clearer.